# Flutter errorr Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: json, flutter

I'm getting data with web socket from server with code below, but can't insert this data to my list.

**Socket Code**

```
socket!.on('post-created', (data) {
      print(data['date']);
      widget.posts.insert(
          0,
          Post(
            date: DateTime.now(),
            id: data['_id'],
            likeCount: 0,
            liked: false,
            photo: data["photo"] != null ? data['photo'] : '',
            text: data['text'],
            userId: UserModelForPost(
              id: data['userId']['_id'],
              photo: data['userId']['photoXs'] != null
                  ? data['userId']['photoXs']
                  : '',
              name: data['userId']['name'],
              surname: data['userId']['surname'],
              username: data['userId']['username'],
            ),
            v: data['__v'],
          ));
    });
```

**data['_id'] prints 611f6c091881dc0023bcf5bd for example**

**Data**

```
{_id: 611f6c091881dc0023bcf5bd, userId: {"photo":"https://storage.googleapis.com/ieeeytusocial-images-272507.appspot.com/7f250a9bb37555ff1405af0eeadfc5bc-xsmall","id":"5d9362ec9b572100172cc648","name":"Emir","surname":"Kutlugün","username":"emir-kutlugun"}, text: aaa, photo: , date: "2021-08-20T08:47:05.244Z", __v: 0, liked: false}
```

**Error**

```
 Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
```

**Fix**

changed post model to that

```
Post newPost = Post(
        date: DateTime.now(),
        id: data['_id'].toString(),
        likeCount: 0,
        liked: false,
        photo: data["photo"] != null ? data['photo'] : '',
        text: data['text'],
        userId: UserModelForPost.fromJson(data['userId']),
        v: 0,
      );
```

Comment: `611f6c091881dc0023bcf5bd` <-- this has letters so it can't be an int. It sees it as a String, but expects an int. If it tries to convert to int, it throws the error. Please copy to us your `Post` class

Comment: You are using a wrong key to get your id. You are using '_id' but it should be 'id' based on your data.

Comment: tried to change, same result

Answer (score 0):

In your model, you have defined the property as an `int`, while your data is actually of type `String`. So simply update your model to have the `id` property as a `String` instead of an `int`.

Comment: changed data['_id] to data['id'].toString() same error

Comment: You have to update your `Post` class. There you probably have defined `id` as `int` while it should be `String`. If not, please provide your code for the `Post` class.

Comment: problem was about UserId section, not related with id as Int, Thanks for your help